# @Value returning null in unit test

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I have a spring boot app with an Endpoint Test Configuration class and a unit test to test my http client. I am trying to get my server address and port from my application.properties which is located in my src/test.(All the classes are in my src/test.)

Here is my config class code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
import com.nulogix.billing.service.PredictionEngineService;
import com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint;
import com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.GetVersionEndPoint;
@Configuration
public class EndPointTestConfiguration {




    @Value("${billing.engine.address}")    
    private String mockAddress;

    @Value("${billing.engine.port}")
    private String mockPort;

    @Bean
    public String getAddress() {
        String serverAddress = "http://" + mockAddress + ":" + mockPort;
        return serverAddress;

    }

    @Bean
    public GetVersionEndPoint getVersionEndPoint() {
        return new GetVersionEndPoint();
    }
```

I annotated the values from my .properties with @value and then created a method that I instantiated with a bean to to return my server address string.

I then use that string value here in my HttpClientTest class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.nulogix.billing.configuration.EndPointTestConfiguration;
import com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp;

@SpringBootTest(classes = EndPointTestConfiguration.class)
public class HttpClientTest {


    @Autowired
    EndPointTestConfiguration endpoint;


    public static final String request_bad  = "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|";
    public static final String request_good = "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0";
    //gets application context
    static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    //call mock server before class

    @BeforeClass
    static public void  setup(){
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplicationBuilder()           
                .sources(MockServerApp.class)
                .build();
        context = springApplication.run();
    }
    //shutdown mock server after class

    @AfterClass
    static public void tearDown(){
        SpringApplication.exit(context);
        }



    @Test
    public void test_bad() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // missing parameter
        String result = Request.Post(endpoint.getAddress())
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(request_bad, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

        Map<?, ?> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(result, Map.class);

        // ensure the key exists
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("status"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("errorMessage"), true);

        // validate values
        Boolean status = (Boolean) resultJsonObj.get("status");
        assertEquals(status, false);
        String errorMessage = (String) resultJsonObj.get("errorMessage");
        assertEquals(errorMessage.contains("Payload has incorrect amount of parts"), true);

    }


    @Test
    public void test_good() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = Request.Post(endpoint.getAddress())
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(request_good, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();

        Map<?, ?> resultJsonObj = new Gson().fromJson(result, Map.class);

        // ensure the key exists
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("status"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("errorMessage"), false);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("HasCopay"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("CopayAmount"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("HasCoinsurance"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("CoinsuranceAmount"), true);
        assertEquals(resultJsonObj.containsKey("version"), true);

        // validate values
        Boolean status = (Boolean) resultJsonObj.get("status");
        assertEquals(status, true);
        String version = (String) resultJsonObj.get("version");
        assertEquals(version, "0.97");

    }

}
```

I use it in the request.post, I didn't want to hardcode in my IP address and port number.

When I run the test it says

```
[ERROR]   HttpClientTest.test_bad:63 NullPointer
[ERROR]   HttpClientTest.test_good:86 NullPointer
```

But I am not sure why it is null? I am pretty sure I have everything instantiated and the string is clearly populated..

My package structure for my config is com.billing.mockserver and my package structure for my unit test is com.billing.ws.endpoint.

Here is my application.properties

```
server.port=9119
server.ssl.enabled=false
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
logging.file=messages
logging.file.max-size=50MB
logging.level.com.nulogix=DEBUG
billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
billing.engine.port=9119
billing.engine.api.version=0.97
billing.engine.core.name=Patient_Responsibility
```

Comment: Try play with `@PropertySource / @ConfigurationProperties` annotations.

Comment: @KamilW Okay, I will inform back

Comment: Try add @TestPropertySource(
    properties = {"billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1", "billing.engine.port=9119"}
) In your test class

Comment: @kamilW I annotated my config class with property source pointing to my app.properties but this did not work

Comment: @QingfeiYuan This did not work either and I want to avoid having to hardcode it in the unit test

Comment: I think making a bean of String type in EndPointTestConfiguration class is not necessary. Also, I don't understand why do you have to set up mock server through setUp and tearDown. Spring boot test can handle the life-cycle. Perhaps you can do some clean up and retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing springboot basic understanding. `@Configuration` class is to initialize other spring beans and other things and are the first classes which get initialized. You should not `@Autowire` `@configuration` class.

In your Configuration class you can either create Spring bean for username and password and autowire that in your test class or directly use `@Value` in your Test class.

Example: in your configuration class you are creating bean of `GetVersionEndPoint` and you can `autowire` that in your Test class.

**Update 2:**

For test classes, you need to add `application.properties` file in `src\test\resource`