# Why wont my Spring Boot unit test load @Value properties in the service class?

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, spring-boot-test

Why wont Spring Boot test load `@Value` properties in the service class?   I have a service class with this property on it.

```
@Value("${azure.storage.connection-string}")
private String connectionString;
```

I am using `JUnit4` .   When this test runs, the `connectionString` property is null.

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:/application-test.yml")
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BlobServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private BlobService blobServiceSpy;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        blobServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(new BlobService(objectMapper));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetExampleBlob() {
        String stubFileId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        PdfBlob pdfBlob = null;
        try {
             pdfBlob = blobServiceSpy.downloadBlobContent(stubFileId);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Test failed.", e);
            Assert.fail();
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull("PDF blob was null.", pdfBlob);
    }
}
```

There is some kind of answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436788/value-returning-null-in-unit-test), but it is very unclear, and the answer needs more info.

This worked but it seems like a "hack":

```
public class BlobServiceTest {

    @Value("${azure.storage.containerName}")
    private String containerName;

    @Value("${azure.storage.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private BlobService blobServiceSpy;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        blobServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(new BlobService(objectMapper));
        //TODO not sure why, but had to setup connectionString property this way
        blobServiceSpy.containerName = this.containerName;
        blobServiceSpy.connectionString = this.connectionString;
    }
```

Why doesn't SpringBootTest wire up those values for me when I create the Spy object?

Answer (score 0):

When you use new to create your `BlobService` spring doesn't know about it an therefore doesn't inject your properties. Try to `@Autowire` your blob service and then wrap it in the spy.